# Android Memory Management 2

Tags: java, android, memory

I am beginner in Android. I made a simple HelloWorld app. And when I went to see how much it is taking space in my disk then I was amazed to see that just a HelloWold app took 35 Mb. Can anyone help me out why it took lots of space and how can we decrease the size of the app.

Comment: Your question is too wide. Put some effort into the investigation yourself. Narrow the problem down.

Comment: You should at least include the code you used. What you consider "simple" may not actually be so simple.